How can I resolve [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: No acceptable representation] error?
I have created a REST API for user registration using Spring Boot in which I for response I'm using GenericResponse class along with ResponseEntity to manipulate the response but I'm facing
[org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: No acceptable representation] error
@PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<GenericResponse<String>> registerUser(@RequestBody @NonNull @NotNull User user) {
        try {
            logger.info("Initial user registration request body: {}", user);
            userService.registerUser(user);

            GenericResponse<String> genericResponse = new GenericResponseBuilder<String>()
                    .setMessage(USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS_MESSAGE).setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value()).build();
            logger.info("User registered successfully: {}", user);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(genericResponse);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error registering user: {}", user, e);
            GenericResponse<String> errorResponse = new GenericResponseBuilder<String>()
                    .setMessage("Failed to register user").setStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()).build();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(errorResponse);
        }
    }

public class GenericResponse<T> {
    private String message;
    private int status;
    private T data;

    private GenericResponse() {
    }

    public static class GenericResponseBuilder<T> {
        private GenericResponse<T> genericResponse;

        public GenericResponseBuilder() {
            genericResponse = new GenericResponse<T>();
        }

        public GenericResponseBuilder<T> setMessage(String message) {
            genericResponse.message = message;
            return this;
        }

        public GenericResponseBuilder<T> setStatus(int status) {
            genericResponse.status = status;
            return this;
        }

        public GenericResponseBuilder<T> setData(T data) {
            genericResponse.data = data;
            return this;
        }

        public GenericResponse<T> build() {
            return this.genericResponse;
        }
    }
}


I tried Hitting the API from Postman & the response I received is:
"status": 406,
"error": "Not Acceptable",
"message": "Acceptable representations: [application/json, application/*+json].",
"path": "/user/register"


can u show the curl command u are trying ?

@RyuzakiL (https://ibb.co/8KJhqDW)

This error arises due to not having public getters for fields in GenericResponse. just add the public getters and problem solved.

I would have used lombok instead. Simply add the @Data and @Builder. Keeps my code short and clean. If you have found the answer, then perhaps you can post it and accept it.
